# Android Bundle getExtras with Calendar Object

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass Calendar Objects from one Activtity to another with intents? I get true for the hasExtra("startDate") but i cannot get the Object itself... sorry for the beginner question.

```
// Activity Two
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("endDate", endDate);
resultIntent.putExtra("startDate", endDate);
setResult(AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);


//Activity One
Bundle newText = data.getExtras();
data.hasExtra("startDate")); // returns true
newText.get("startDate") // returns null
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you mean `java.util.Calendar`, that implements `Serializable`, so you can use `putExtra()` [and `getSerializableExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Hi yes I mean Java.util.Calendar. But thats not working on my side. returns null as well. Do I have to serialize it first?

Comment: @Florian: No, that is not necessary. When and how are you calling the `// Activity Two` code? Are you sure that `endDate` is not `null` at that point? Also note that you are supplying the value of `endDate` for both extras.

Comment: Shame on me... I called it before it was initialized... Thanks a lot! Your Solution works like a charm!